# connecting app account with facebook and twitter account

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, twitter

So I have an app account in which it can login using facebook/twitter or as well using the app account it self (username/email and password). Sometimes in an app I see they allow to connect the app account with twitter and facebook account, how do they actually make these connections? What I am confused is that if I have a User object (stored in the database) then what do I need to store additionally in that User class to represent the connection to a user facebook twitter and facebook account? Can someone give me an insight to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically all you'd store would be the facebook user id and the twitter user id. When someone wants to connect an account (say Facebook) you'd ask them to log into their app account, then log into their facebook account. You'd then save their facebook user id into the appropriate field in your User object. Later on they can then log in with their facebook account and you can look up the right User using the facebook user id field. Twitter would work the same.

Comment: You'd generally want their access tokens stored, too.

Comment: Well, I'd think that since access tokens typically expire (unless you're explicitly requesting offline access) those strictly speaking don't go in the User object. The user id is the prime identifying artifact so you'd store that: access tokens are generated artifacts so you may or may not want to store them but you can always get a new one by having the user log in again.

Comment: Twitter access tokens don't expire, and a lot of apps on Facebook request a permanent one. Even if you don't, it may be useful to store the most recent Facebook one in case the session data expires before the access token does.

Comment: Ah. Good point about the twitter ones: didn't know they don't expire them, so that's probably worth saving. I guess my Facebook usage behavior is bleeding into my answer: I explicitly do not use any app that asks for offline access, but if @adit gets an offline_access token then yes, he should save it.

Comment: well so userid and access token seems to be the answer here.. so with the userid and access token I can query the user's facebook/twitter details?

Comment: Yep, that's all you need. Well, that and a suitable library or chunk of code.

Comment: stupid question, if a user sign in using their twitter account first and then click on the sign up link to sign in again, then that user would have 2 accounts.. correct?

Comment: That would depend on your implementation: you could make it do that, or you could write the logic to rationalize it.

Comment: @adit did you ever solve this....I would also like to connect my current_user to their Facebook, but I do not know where to start or what to do in the database?